# 301 htaccess redirect (ssl) old site to new site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm currently changing my domain name. I've been experimenting with htaccess code but failed eventually. I've tried various 301 redirecting sites to generate codes but none of them are working correctly.

How can I redirect following old domain urls to new domain urls?

- `https://www.olddomain.com/` to `https://www.newdomain.com/`
- `https://www.olddomain.com/page-1/` to `https://www.newdomain.com/page-1/`
- `https://www.olddomain.com/page-2/` to `https://www.newdomain.com/page-2/`

Last code I've tried.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^page-1/$ https://www.newdomain.com/page-1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^page-2/$ https://www.newdomain.com/page-2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: sure I've updated the post. thanks

Comment: Your rules look fine. What is the error?

Comment: it's not redirecting.... one more thin i think i should mention... I doubt that since both sites in the same hosting and under same ip address that's why redirection is not working properly :(

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.